# gynecomastia-man-boobs tag needs adjusting

Tags: support

the tag [gynecomastia-man-boobs](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gynecomastia-man-boobs) needs to be renamed to gynecomastia and [synonyms](https://health.stackexchange.com/tags/gynecomastia-man-boobs/synonyms) of [man-boobs](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/man-boobs) and the **UK spelling [gynaecomastia](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gynaecomastia)** needs setting up, yet I don't seem to be able to do either.

Can this be arranged?

Comment: We need mod power for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Narusan pointed out in the comment: "We need mod power for that".

Except that synonyms might be suggested and approved by ordinary users:

https://health.stackexchange.com/tags/gynecomastia-man-boobs/synonyms

says:

> Users with more than 1250 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.

In the sorry state of affairs for this site that brings us back to the opening paragraph of this answer since the combined conditions of active user, reputation >1250  and a tag score >5 for suggestions and tag score also needed for  voting on that suggestion creates a pool of potential activists to do so that is quite small.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sub>1: Just a quick guess, unverified, as actually counting that number would lead into a depressive state.</sub>